# How do \left | and \right | actually work?

Tags: math-mode, fontspec, tex-core, unicode

How do `\left |` and `\right |` actually work, specifically when packages like `fontspec` or `mathspec` are involved and unicode fonts are used?

I sort of understand how other kinds of brackets and parentheses are constructed from parts in the `U+2300` Unicode block.
What glyph is actually used to typeset **vertical bars** in that kind of context? Not `U+007C` or `U+2223`? Or are there some tricks involved?

Besides other sources and searches I've tried to look it up in the TeX distro itself, had high hopes for `tex/plain/base`, but - no luck?

Comment: it is font specifc, the extension glyphs do not have to have a numeric encoding

Answer (score 2):

The extension glyphs are specified by the font.

Looking at Latin Modern Math

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\showoutput
\begin{document}


$( \Bigg( \left(\rule{1pt}{1cm}\right.$
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
.......\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10
```

so the large ( come from U+f06cb Private Use area (in this font)

and

```
.......\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 ⎛
......\glue -2.49 plus 2.29002
......\hbox(4.98+0.0)x8.75, direction TLT
.......\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 ⎜
......\glue -4.98 plus 4.78001
......\hbox(4.98+0.0)x8.75, direction TLT
.......\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 ⎜
......\glue -4.98 plus 4.78001
......\hbox(4.98+0.0)x8.75, direction TLT
.......\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 ⎜
......\glue -4.98 plus 4.78001
......\hbox(4.98+0.0)x8.75, direction TLT
.......\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 ⎜
......\glue -2.49 plus 2.29002
......\hbox(14.95+0.0)x8.75, direction TLT
.......\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 ⎝
```

so the constructed one is

```
 U+239b LEFT PARENTHESIS UPPER HOOK
 U+239c LEFT PARENTHESIS EXTENSION
 U+239c LEFT PARENTHESIS EXTENSION
 U+239c LEFT PARENTHESIS EXTENSION
 U+239d LEFT PARENTHESIS LOWER HOOK
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, the method is more or less comprehensible with various brackets and parentheses. It's vertical bars when used with modifiers like `\left` that baffle me. There are no obvious parts for those in the U+2300 block. 

Are you saying the method for vertical bars/brackets actually differs with regard to the specific font used?

Comment: @yury10578 Yes, the font can define arbitrary glyphs to use. In general they might not even be mapped to any Unicode codepoint but could be specific only for this usecase.

Comment: @yury10578 everything is font specific the parts do not need to be glyphs that are mapped to an encoding, the font can reference glyphs by their internal glyph names

Comment: So, guys, thank you, and would you advise, where in the TeX distro are `\left` and `\right` defined?
It sort of 'must' be in the plain-tex part, but grep'ing doesn't take me far. Maybe I'm just missing it on screen, or maybe it is defined in a too complicated way for a primitive grep search to catch?

Comment: @yury10578 not in plain text it is a tex primitive so defined in the web (pascal) source of the tex executable. you can find tex.web on ctan

Comment: @yury10578 here https://texdoc.org/serve/knuth/61#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A3161%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22FitH%22%7D%2C664.392%5D

Comment: that is the version in tex, the version in luatex for opentype is same basic idea though, getting the data from the font

Comment: Thank you, David. To sum it up, I should look for the tex.web, which is the source of plain TeX, and also for the source of one of the modern variants, viz luatex, to see how it's done with modern font containers?
PS there is no tex.web on CTAN (anymore?)

Comment: @yury10578 source of tex, not plain tex, which is a macro package like latex. I link to the typeset tex.web above

Comment: @David Carlisle, yes, I've noticed and followed the link, thank you, and I've found another instance by myself, but there is no tex.web on CTAN.
So do I get this right, tex.web (or its PDF-rendering you linked) is the source for the TeX-the-macro-package (not TeX-the-typesetting-virtual-machine)?
And to learn about Opentype specifics, I should look in the equivalent module in one of the modern variants, like Luatex?

Comment: @yury10578 it is on ctan https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/systems/knuth/dist/tex/tex.web  This is the source of the tex program not any macros

Answer (score 1):

For Latin Modern, one can look at the vertical line `U+007C`. Screenshot from FontForge:

[image: screenshot]

Here we can see, that there is the base glyph and then no less than seven variants (`divides.v1`, `divides.v2` and so on, up to `divides.v7`). If one needs larger, there will be a larger, extensible one built with one `divides.bt` at the bottom, one `divides.tp` at the top, and as many `divides.ex` as needed. The recipe on how to glue them together is given there as well, look at the numbers.

Other fonts might (will, likely) have a different number of variants, and some might lack an extensible recipe. No guarantees.

Comment: Thank you, and could you point me to the file in distros' which actually implements this? I've tried primitive grepping, to no avail.

Comment: BTW, you might want to specify that in modern versions of FontForge (mine's 20220308) this table has been partitioned and the 'components'' names for extensible openings/closings (e.g. `divides.v1 divides.v2` etc. in your example) are to be found at **Element -> Other info -> MATH info** menu path, **Vert. variants** item.

Answer (score 1):

After digging in the sources I'm giving sort of a half-answer to my own question, subject to eventual elaboration by people better with these matters.

So, when using unicode fonts `fontspec` package (eventually helped by `mathspec` or `unicode-math`) is almost a given. The difference **between** getting *scaling vertical bar delimiters* in legacy CMEX or not getting them at all **and** getting scaling vertical bar delimiters *in the font of your choice* is made by using (or not using) `\DeclareMathDelimiter{|}...`

I'm leaving out the rest of the parameters intentionally, as these depend on how you are specifically proceeding with `fontspec` and such; `fontspec` seems to leave out that kind of definition for `|`.